# Storing data of user when they log in?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a website in which users log in, and then I want to load a lot of information about him/her. I want to load, for example, all the id's of the people they follow. I use `$_SESSION` to store the user id/other basic stuff, but I'm afraid that for arrays I'll need something else to not waste space on the server. I thought about cookies, but I don't know if that's really a good idea. What can I use to store arrays securely without taking space on the server?

Comment: You would do the query when you need the data. Don't just assume you would need the data later on.

Comment: @JustinWood So you're suggesting that I'll just query the data over and over again?

Comment: No, I am suggesting that you only pull out the data that you need when you need it. If there is some reason that you need to do a massive query every couple of seconds, look into something like memcached.

Comment: @JustinWood It's a social network-style website, so if a user sees a picture, let's say, I need to know if he/she "liked" that picture or any of the comments. This is why I suggest to load an array of all the comments'/pictures' id's so I don't have to check each time.

Comment: Here is a good piece of advice to live by. Don't pre optimize your code. It is possible if you structure your queries properly, you will have little to no issues in grabbing that information every time you meed it.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: You can't store anything securely on the client (Cookies, local storage etc.).

Store an identifier (user id) in a session and query the database on each page load.

If you're worried about performance, you should look into caching your templates.

**Edit:** I saw you mentioned it's a social service. [Here's a post from Facebook about their use of memcached.](https://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=39391378919) Other users [include YouTube, Reddit, Twitter, Tumblr and Wikipedia.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memcached)

Comment: But let's say a user clicks on a picture, and I want to see if he/she "liked" it or any of the comments in the picture. Would I need to check each time? Wouldn't it make sense to just load all the pictures/comments that the user liked and then check?

Comment: Unless you're running a web service that's receiving thousands of hits every moment, you shouldn't be worried. You could calculate the "likes" regularly and store the sum somewhere inside your database for a crude cache, but in a real world case, you'd be using something like memcache.

Comment: I have the sum stored, but the problem is querying the data each time. I load an image, I have to load all of that info, rather than having everything set when the user logs in.

Comment: Again, that's what cache is for. Storing data in a session or an array somewhere just isn't a scalable solution.

Comment: Memcached is a relatively expensive ($$$) solution, since data is stored in RAM. The big advantage of memcached is that's it's clustered, meaning you can store an (almost) infinite number of sessions as long as you keep adding servers. I would generally not recommend using Memcached until your system is big enough to need a load balancer and multiple webservers.

Comment: I'm not saying it's the best, but there must be a reason the biggest web services out there are using it. [Here's an crash course in how it works.](https://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/TutorialCachingStory). I'm not trying to "sell" you the idea of implementing memcached, and I do think you're thinking about performance too early in the development cycle. It's nice to keep in mind, but not down to microseconds.

Answer (score 0):

If you're worried about space sessions (session files) are the best way of doing this. Other solutions would can store sessions in memory, which might be faster, but you only have a small amount of RAM. Session files are stored on the hard disk and hard disk space should be cheap and plenty.

If your session files are truly big, you should consider using [**igbinary**](https://github.com/igbinary/igbinary#how-to-use) to serialize the data for sessions. While normal session data is in plain text format, igbinary data is in a much smaller binary format. [Igbinary is available on PECL](http://pecl.php.net/package/igbinary).

> About 50% reduction in storage requirement can be expected. Specific
>   number depends on your data.

---

Putting the data in a cookie is a bad idea. Cookie data is send back and forth on each request. Big cookies mean a lot of traffic and a slow site.